# Using one observable to synchronize another observable

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

I want to synchronize an observable using another one used as clock, below is reported an example.

```
Main:     ---------abc----------------------------------
Clock:    -x-----x-----x-----x-----x-----x-----x-----x--
Expected: -------------a-----b-----c--------------------
```

I tried to achieve this synchronization using the Zip method, similar to an example described in RX documentation (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html):

```cs
mainValues.Zip(clockValues, (mainValue,clockValue) => mainValue)
```

the problem is that when I tested this implementation, it didn't work. Below there is the test I wrote to check the expected behaviour:

```
scheduler = new TestScheduler();


var mainValues = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(100, Notification.CreateOnNext('a')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(101, Notification.CreateOnNext('b')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(102, Notification.CreateOnNext('c')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(103, Notification.CreateOnNext('d')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(104, Notification.CreateOnNext('e')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(105, Notification.CreateOnNext('f')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(106, Notification.CreateOnNext('g')),
    new Recorded<Notification<char>>(107, Notification.CreateOnCompleted<char>()));

var clockValues = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(70, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(90, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(110, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(130, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(150, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(170, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(190, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(210, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(230, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(250, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(270, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(290, Notification.CreateOnNext(0L)),
    new Recorded<Notification<long>>(310, Notification.CreateOnCompleted<long>()));


var res = scheduler.Start(() => mainValues.Zip(clockValues, (mainValue, clockValue) => mainValue), 0, 70, long.MaxValue);
```

And here below the expected values and what I really got (described as comment):

```
res.Messages.AssertEqual(
    OnNext(110, 'a'), // Expected: 110, a - Actual: 100, a
    OnNext(130, 'b'), // Expected: 130, b - Actual: 110, b
    OnNext(150, 'c'), // Expected: 150, c - Actual: 130, c
    OnNext(170, 'd'), // Expected: 170, d - Actual: 150, d
    OnNext(190, 'e'), // Expected: 190, e - Actual: 170, e
    OnNext(210, 'f'), // Expected: 210, f - Actual: 190, f
    OnNext(230, 'g'));// Expected: 230, g - Actual: 210, g
```

**What is the problem? Is it correct use Zip to synchronize two observable? Do I use the TestScheduler incorrectly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Create<char?>(o =>
        {
            IDisposable inner = null;
            IDisposable subscription = 
                mainValues
                    .Publish(mvs =>
                    {
                        var q = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<char>();
                        inner = mvs.Subscribe(mv => q.Enqueue(mv));
                        return clockValues.Select(x => q.Count > 0 ? q.Dequeue() : (char?)null);
                    })
                    .Subscribe(o);
            return new CompositeDisposable(inner, subscription);
        });

query.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
scheduler.Start();
```

Let me know if that works the way you want it to. If it does I'll pop in some explanation.

Comment: Only issue I can see is that this is not threadsafe. We don't know that the upstream Observables run on the same thread.

Comment: @Aron - If the upstream observables behave under the normal Rx contract it should be fine - otherwise drop a call to `Synchronize` before the `Publish`.

Comment: **It works**, I added only to your solution a `Where` condition to remove the null char from `subscription`. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Does changing

```
mainValues.Zip(clockValues, (mainValue,clockValue) => mainValues)
```

...to:

```
mainValues.Zip(clockValues, (mainValue,clockValue) => mainValue)
```

fix it?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I wrote wrong in the first example ,in fact in the second one I wrote correctly the Zip method. I'll modify the first example.